# Simple grid view with buttons

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.android

How can i make simple grid view with buttons? I have tried the most obvious solution but it doesn't work. Tutorials are really bad (for me), and the simples solution dosn't work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <GridView
      android:id="@+id/gridView"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="155.5dp"
      android:numColumns="2"
      android:padding="10dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="68.0dp"
      android:background="#009967">
      <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button1" />
  </GridView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Spinners`, `GridViews` and `ListViews` are subclasses of android's `AdapterViews`. This means that they have no child elements, and they are dynamically created programmatically using custom adapters that extend the `BaseAdapter` class.

[image: Android AdapterViews]

To do what you need to, first create an empty activity and name it `GridActivity`. Edit the activity_grid.xml layout file to a an empty `GridView`.
Example -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.user.gridbuttonview.GridActivity"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:id="@+id/activity_grid"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp" />
```

Then create a new class in your project named `ButtonAdapter` such as the follows -

Mind that the total number of buttons can be set in the variable `total_btns` which is 20 by default.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ButtonAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private Context mContext;
    private int btn_id;
    private int total_btns = 20;

    public ButtonAdapter(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return total_btns;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup)
    {
        Button btn;

        if (view == null) {
            btn = new Button(mContext);
            btn.setText("Button " + (++btn_id));
        } else {
            btn = (Button) view;
        }

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Button #" + (i + 1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        return btn;
    }
}
```

lastly, change your `GridActivity` class' `onCreate` method to set the gridView on creation.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_grid);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.activity_grid);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ButtonAdapter(this));
}
```

This will create your grid view that you want, with buttons. And once you trigger the grid activity, you get the following output -

[image]

The click listener in the adapter class can be edited to handle each click. Hope it helps!